# Remove sublists with duplicate elements within

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I have this list

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort[#] & /@ Tuples[Range[4], 3]]
```

which gives me

{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1,
2, 4}, {1, 3, 3}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 4}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2,
2, 4}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 4}, {3, 4,
4}, {4, 4, 4}}

and I want elements such as {1,1,1} or {3,3,4} removed on the grounds that they are sublists with repeated elements within

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combine [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) with [`DuplicateFreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DuplicateFreeQ.html).

```
Sort /@ Select[Tuples[Range[4], 3], 
   DuplicateFreeQ] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}

A shorter and more efficient way is to simply use [`Subsets`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html).

```
Subsets[Range[4], {3}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}

Comment: Thanks, that was quick 

So, the whole solution would then be 

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Select[Tuples[Range[4], 3], DuplicateFreeQ]]
```

Comment: @RuthLazkoz (and @user1066), thanks, I missed this.

Comment: Many thanks again

Answer (score 7):

Another way using `Cases`:

```
list = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Tuples[Range[4], 3]];

Cases[list, x_List /; DuplicateFreeQ[x] === True]

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceAt`:

```
list = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Tuples[Range[4], 3]];

ReplaceAt[list, x_List /; ! DuplicateFreeQ[x] :> Nothing, All]

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Tuples[Range[4], 3] // Select[DuplicateFreeQ] // 
 DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]
```

or

```
Tuples[Range[4], 3] // Select[Apply[UnsameQ]] // 
 DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]
```

---

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 3):

```
Cases[list, {a_, b_, c_} /; a != b != c]
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the list generated by `Tuples`:

```
Pick[#, CountDistinct /@ #, 3] &[Union[Sort /@ Tuples[Range[4], 3]]]

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}} *)
```